# Unknown process outputs binary results, how to prove that this process is (or not) a Bernoulli trial

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sampling, binomial-distribution, inference, goodness-of-fit

I have an unknown process that produces binary results. I am trying to determine if this process is a Bernoulli trial.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_trial):

> In the theory of probability and statistics, a Bernoulli trial (or binomial trial) is a random experiment with exactly two possible outcomes, "success" and "failure", in which the probability of success is the same every time the experiment is conducted.

I do not know the actual success rate, if the success rate of each trial is equal, or if the trials are independent from each other.

However, I can collect data from the process in sequential trials with its corresponding successful trials.

Initial set of trials yielded 5 successes out of 999 trials.

- Success 1 was on trial 196
- Success 2 was on trial 388
- success 3 was on trial 593
- Success 4 was on trial 792
- Success 5 was on trial 999

**What is the ideal way to demonstrate (perhaps with test statistics) if this process is or is not a Bernoulli trial.** i.e.

- I already know it outputs binary results.
- does each trial have an equal or varying probability of success?
- are the trials independent?

---

Context:

A computer game uses an unspecified item drop system. Most item drop systems in computer games are Bernoulli trials with equal probability of success (i.e. an equal drop chance). However, I suspect that this particular system uses a count to determine a successful drop (e.g. success after ~200 trials). I want to design an experiment that will prove that the drop system uses an equal drop chance (Bernoulli trial) or a different system (e.g. a count based system).

---

My background:

I had only very basic statistics lesson in college many years ago. I am very fuzzy with test statistics. I have fair understanding of Bernoulli trials and binomial distributions.

---

My attempt:

Since I am trying to determine if the process is a Bernoulli trial with an equal chance of success p, if I can demonstrate that separate cumulative trials have different p, I can prove that the drop system does not use Bernoulli trial with an equal success chance.

To do this I collected 3 sets of data. Set A was a sequential 999 trials that resulted in 5 successes as stated above. Set B was 5 x 190 trials with a gap in between them. Set C was the gap between the 5 sets of 190 trials in B. i.e.

999 trials (A) - 190 (B) - 15 (C) - 190 (B) - 11 (C) - 190 (B) - 9 (C) - 190 (B) - 1 (C) - 190 (B) - 3 (C) - 190 (B)

This sampling yielded:

- A: 5 successes in 999 trials
- B: 0 successes in 950 trials
- C: 5 successes in 39 trials

The reason it is sampled this way is because I suspected that the drop counter is between 190 and 210, and that the drop counter resets after each successful trial. Every time I obtain a successful trial in Set C, I switch back to collecting Set B.

Using Clopper-Pearson interval (a.k.a. 'exact' method), α = 0.05, I calculated the interval of which Success chance p lies in, for each set of data.

- Set A: Success rate P<sub>A</sub>: 0.00163 - 0.01164, 95% confidence
- Set B: Success rate P<sub>B</sub>: 0.00003 - 0.00388, 95% confidence
- Set C: Success rate P<sub>C</sub>: 0.04297 - 0.2743, 95% confidence

Since,

P<sub>C</sub> ≠ P<sub>A</sub>

P<sub>C</sub> ≠ P<sub>B</sub>

I conclude that the drop system observed is not a binomial experiment with equal success chance.

Is this an acceptable solution? If not, what is the correct method to approach this problem?

---

Research:

I've read through several posts related to this topic, however they are difficult for me to understand and I cannot be sure how to use those solutions on this particular question.

[Test if two binomial distributions are statistically different from each other](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113602/test-if-two-binomial-distributions-are-statistically-different-from-each-other)

[Test if two binomial distributions comply with the same p](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80123/test-if-two-samples-of-binomial-distributions-comply-with-the-same-p)

[Is there a test for independence in a Bernoulli process?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20563/is-there-a-test-for-independence-in-a-bernoulli-process)

[Test on binomial distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11537/tests-on-binomial-distribution)

[Probablity distribution for different probabilities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9510/probability-distribution-for-different-probabilities)

[estimate probability mass function from observed sample](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148985/estimate-probability-mass-function-from-observed-samples?rq=1)

Comment: From a statistical point of view, any variable that is strictly yes/ no is a binomial. A binomial can have a different probabilities of success.

Comment: I'm sorry if I used the wrong terminology. Should I have used binomial distribution instead? If the the probability of success is fixed?

Comment: It's fine to want to know if the probability is fixed or varying. It's just that in either case it's a binomial.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, any stricly binary (yes/no) variable is a Bernoulli variable, which is the same as an Binomial variable with parameter $n=1$ (and some $p$). There is no more possibilities, since such a variable has its distribution totally identified by the probability $p$ of occurence.

But when you have more than one bernoulli variable, and sum them up, to get the total number of occurences, there are other possibilities. Let there be $n$ such variables, with probability of occurence $p_i$ each. When all the probabilities $p_i$ are identical $p$, and the events are independent, the sum $X=X_1 + \dotso + X_n$ has the binomial distribution with parameters $n,p$. But with unequal probabilities and/or dependence, we get other possibilities.

First, the case with independence but enequal probabilities $p_i$, 
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}\DeclareMathOperator{\V}{\mathbb{V}}
\bar{p} = \frac1n \sum p_i.
$$ 
Then the expectation $\E X$ still has the binomial value $np$ (by linearity of expectation), but the variance $\V X$ differs:
$$
\V X = \V (\sum X_i) = \sum \V X_i = \sum p_i(1-p_i) \\
     =  \dots = n\bar{p}(1-\bar{p}) - \sum (p_i - \bar{p})^2 \\
     <  n \bar{p}(1-\bar{p})
$$
(after some algebra), so it is always smaller than the binomial variance!

There are of course many other possibilities, let us take the case of $n=2$, equal probabilities, but dependence:

Suppose that
$$
    P(X_1=0,X_2=0)= (1-p)^2 (1+\theta) \\
    P(X_1=0,X_2=1)= p(1-p) (1-\psi) \\
    P(X_1=1,X_2=0)= p(1-p) (1-\psi) \\
    P(X_1=1,X_2=1)= p^2 (1+\theta) 
$$
(If you fix $p, \theta$, you can determine $\psi$. I leave that as an exercise ...) with a positive $\theta$, this is a kind of positive dependence, positive covariance. If I got my algebra right, the variance of $X=X_1 + X_2$ can be found to be:
$$
\V X = 2 p (1-p) + \theta p^2
$$
so that, with a positive $\theta$, the variance is larger than binomial, but with a negative $\theta$, the variance is smaller than binomial!

Comment: When the trials are independent, the binomial case always has higher variance, not lower. As an example, let $p_1={{1} \over {3}},$$p_2= {{2} \over {3}},$ and $\bar{p} = {{1} \over {2}}.$ Then the variance is ${{4} \over {9}}$ for the unequal case, but ${{1} \over {2}}$ for the binomial case.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @soakley, in the case of unequal $p_i$, the variance $\operatorname{Var}X= \sum p_i(1-p_i) = \sum [(p_i-\bar p) + \bar p][(1-\bar p) -(p_i-\bar p)] = \ldots = n\bar p(1-\bar p) - \sum (p_i - \bar p)^2$

Comment: I have calculated the variance of the sample data I listed above:

$$ 
S^2=\frac{\sum (Xi - \bar{X})^2}{(n-1)}= 0.004985
$$
And the binomial variance
$$
\sigma^2=np(1-p)= 4.9750
$$

And since $S^2<\sigma^2$,

Can I conclude that the process in which the sample was derived from, most likely does not have an equal probability of success, or a negative $\theta$ (dependence / covariance)?

Comment: Edit: I must be calculating the wrong variance because as long as there's 5 success in the sample (n=999) I get the same variance, despite how close or far apart the successful trials are.

Comment: I've did additional research and it seems that this question can be answered using goodness of fit to a binomial distribution. Perhaps this is what you are suggesting @kjetilbhalvorsen? Is the Variance of X in this case the variance from the expected value (i.e. 199.8) or the mean of the probabilities (i.e. 0.005005)

Comment: Yes, you could use goodness of fit to a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I have a statistical test that might help you.

Let me first note that you want to know if your sequence of observations is a **independent and identically distributed** (i.i.d.) sequence of Bernoulli random variables. The problem is that a sequence can fail to be i.i.d. for a variety of reasons and there are a lot of [randomness tests](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xkrhovj/lectures/2005_PA168_Statistical_Testing_slides.pdf) out there, each one better suited for a particular way in which a sequence fails to be i.i.d.. I believe that the [number of runs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test) test or the longest runs test (you can find its description in [this book](https://www.crcpress.com/Nonparametric-Statistical-Inference-Fifth-Edition/Gibbons-Chakraborti/p/book/9781420077612) ) are two good candidates for you problem.

If none of the previous tests work let me propose a alternative approach. Let's suppose we have a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli r.v. $\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$, i.e., $X_i\sim Ber(p)$, for all $i$.

Now we will define the following random variables:

- $Y_1$ is the number of $0$ we shaw before the first $1$;
- $Y_2$ is the number of $0$ after the first $1$ that we shaw before the second $1$.
- In a similar way we define $Y_j$ for any value of $j\in\{1,2,\ldots\}$.

The interesting thing here is that (if we assume a i.i.d. sequence) all $Y_j$ have the same distribution which is a geometric distribution with success probability $p$, $geo(p)$:

$$\mathbb P (Y_j = k) = (1-p)^kp$$

Now we have our test. If your sequence is not a i.i.d. one, the distribution of the $Y_j$ you constructed from it would not be close to a $geo(p)$ distribution. This can be tested with any [goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit) test. If you have no previous knowledge of the value of $p$ you can resort to estimating it from the sample.